# Accessing stdin during systemd boot

Tags: bash, sh, fedora, boot, systemd

I have a script which solicits a numeric input from the user while booting the computer.  The computer is running Fedora 16. It used work, on Fedora 13, but after the upgrade

```
read INTEGER
```

returns immediately, without catching any user input.  I tried

```
read INTEGER
wait $!
```

but (predictably) that too doesn't work.  The script is run from a systemd service file (see comments below). It *must* be run as root, and *must* started before the user logs in. It currently calls bash as its interpreter, but with some effort, that could be changed. Can anyone help return this script to normal?

Extra credit: In F13, it used to halt booting for user input (as desired) but the input was not displayed as the user typed. Is there a way to add this functionality?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your specific problem, but I do know where to start looking: look into how systemd works, which is the new init replacement.  Writing a new systemd file is actually quite easy, and putting your script execution in it is easy as well.  But the problem is you need systemd to let you access stdin, and that's where I'm not sure if there is a magic config token that will let you do that.  A quick read of the systemd.unit man page doesn't show one to me quickly.

Comment: Hm.  I've put it in a systemd.service file, which runs as expected, but still won't accept keyboard input.  Am using `type=oneshot`, `WantedBy=graphical.target`, `After=multiuser.target`. Will shortly try `WantedBy=multiuser.target` to see if that helps.

Comment: Putting it in the `multiuser.target` "queue" (for want of a better word" makes it start visibly, but doesn't interrupt the startup for help.  @WesHardaker, do you know what starts systemd?

Comment: systemd is the very first thing run after the kernel starts.  IE, it's PID #1.  You could always boot from initd instead, but honestly that's not the correct path forward as it looks like systemd is here to stay (and I agree: it should; it's better, although I had to read up a bit to learn why I wanted it).  Plus, starting with F16 they're getting rid of all the older init scripts and requiring systemd .service files for everything.

Comment: which would also allow you to use /proc/cmdline and env to get an integer (IIRC, when you pass VAR=value on the kernel command line, the init process sees it as an environment variable and everything else goes to /proc/cmdline and/or the argv of the init process)

Comment: have you tried using something like [`systemd-ask-password`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-ask-password.html)?

Answer (score 1):

During a normal boot, the keyboard is connected to Plymouth (I believe)

On Fedora, I believe you want something like:

```
 plymouth ask-question --prompt="Pick a number between 0 and ∞" \
     --command="/usr/bin/numberguesser"
```

possibly with

```
     --dont-pause-progress
```

That *should* display the Plymouth prompt screen, not dissimilar from the way that crypto filesystems prompt for their passwords.

Note that `/usr/bin/numberguesser` would only get the string entered piped in on its standard input.

*Untested*, sorry :-(